# Multiple conditions for r data.table calculation

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like the following:

```
   Sim j active cost
1:   1 1      1  100
2:   1 2      1  125
3:   1 3      0  200
4:   1 4      1  250
5:   2 1      1  100
6:   2 2      0  50
7:   2 3      0  125
8:   2 4      1  200

dt <- data.table(Sim = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
             j = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
             active = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
             cost = c(100, 125, 200, 250, 100, 50, 125, 200))
```

I want to add a column 'incr_cost' that subtracts the cost in each row i from the cost in a different row, which I'll call row k, where row k meets these conditions:

- sim_k = sim_i
- active_k = 1
- j_k < j_i
- row k contains the largest j of all rows meeting the 3 above conditions

For rows where j=1, incr_cost can just be NA.

In my example, the solution would look like:

```
   Sim j active cost incr_cost
1:   1 1      1  100        NA
2:   1 2      1  125        25
3:   1 3      0  200        75
4:   1 4      1  250       125
5:   2 1      1  100        NA
6:   2 2      0   50       -50
7:   2 3      0  125        25
8:   2 4      1  200       100
```

It seems like this is similar to applications of shift, except that instead of 'shifting' on the data.table as is, I want to shift on row-reduced data.table where rows not meeting my conditions are filtered out. I'm having a hard time understanding how to identify the row that has the largest j value that is less than my current row (and meets the other two conditions).

The following works except that it does not consider whether a row is active when selecting row k:

```
dt[, incr_cost := cost - shift(cost, fill=NA), by=Sim]
```

I am using r data.table, but non-data.table solutions are also welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a rolling join:

```
dt[, v := 
  cost - .SD[.(active = 1, Sim = Sim, j = j - 1), on=.(active, Sim, j), roll=TRUE, x.cost]]

   Sim j active cost   v
1:   1 1      1  100  NA
2:   1 2      1  125  25
3:   1 3      0  200  75
4:   1 4      1  250 125
5:   2 1      1  100  NA
6:   2 2      0   50 -50
7:   2 3      0  125  25
8:   2 4      1  200 100
```

This looks up the tuples `.(active = 1, Sim = Sim, j = j - 1)` and when an exact match is not found, "rolls" to the last `j` value that fits, if any.

*How it works*

In `j` of `x[i, j]`, `.SD` is just a shorthand for the table itself, the "Subset of Data".

In `j` of a join `x[i, on=, roll=, j]`...

- the prefix `x.*` refers to columns of `x` (here, `.SD`); and similarly
- `i.*` would be a prefix for columns of `i` (here, the tuples).

(OP's use of `j` as a name might make this confusing. I mean `j`, the argument in `DT[i, j, ...]`.)

Comment: Works great, and the 'how it works' is super helpful. Thank you so much!!